# Unable to write to commit message inputBox

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have the below code, which has been working fine for several months, but at some point it stopped working, and I simply can't figure out why it isn't working anymore.

I did some debugging and for some reason the `repository` is undefined.

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { Repository } from './git';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand("my_extension.my_command",
        (repository: Repository) => {
            repository.inputBox.value = "commit message goes here";
        }));
}
```

Comment: where is the focus when you invoke this command?

Comment: I have tried having the focus in the in inputBox but I'm getting the same error.
Earlier it didn't care where the focus was.

Comment: how do you suppose that the argument of the command is a `Repository`, and what is a `Repository`

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. This project was just something I threw together quite quick without really knowing anything about this stuff, but I got something something working.
The full source code is here: https://github.com/Gaardsholt/vscode-whatthecommit

Comment: there is no specification of what the argument of the command will be if it is a menu command. I tested it and now there are no arguments (all are `undefined`). Where did you find this UI definition/interface for `Repository`. Maybe in an older version of VSC they passed in some object representing the UI of the View.

Comment: I used this one: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/git/src/api/git.d.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently if you have more than one repository open, my original code worked just fine, but if you only had one repository open, then `repository` was undefined and I had to use the `GetRepo` function to get the repository.

So my final code ended up looking like this:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import { Repository } from './git';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand("my_extension.my_command",
        (repository: Repository) => {
            repository = GetRepo(repository);

            repository.inputBox.value = "commit message goes here";
        }, { repository: true }));
}

function GetRepo(repository: Repository | undefined): Repository {
    if (repository === undefined) {
        let gitExtension = vscode.extensions.getExtension<GitExtension>('vscode.git').exports;
        let api = gitExtension.getAPI(1);
        repository = api.repositories[0];
    }

    return repository;
}
```

Comment: I would not classify that as a `this` context, something undocumented happens behind the scene, this might be used in other views too